# Google Analytics mobile app - No views found

Tags: android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I am using Firebase to develop an Android app for API > 21. The Google Analytics website works correctly, data is coming in and DebugView registers events on my development device. The Firebase Console website also aggregates the analytics data correctly. However, the Google Analytics mobile app for Android shows a "No Views Found." splash screen. I would like to view the analytics data natively from the mobile app, rather than using a browser to interface the Google Analytics website. It's also a concern that I have somehow botched the setup when the Google Analytics mobile app does not load correctly. Any thoughts?

```
'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.2.1' // app level dependency
FirebaseAnalytics analytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this); // get reference to analytics framework
analytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.LOGIN, bundle); // send test event
```

Comment: use adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE to find if its logging event in console correctly https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/events?platform=android

Comment: The logs are correct. The reason is described in the accepted answer ... the Google Analytics app does not currently support Firebase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Google Analytics mobile app does not currently support Firebase and App+Web properties.
[Reference](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.giant&hl=en_US&reviewId=gp%3AAOqpTOGvsOv2PkUwkBgLD-_k0Gh2LH2iYlzqWymNgCQQgw34_sRJ88dFukPMPnEXhtSmidOta19JbMpWBgbpqyQ)

Comment: This limitation has been addressed now. [Release notes](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/9164320#82120)